# Using Svelte, Fable and Tauri

Tags: javascript, svelte, fable-f#, tauri

I'm creating a Tauri app that uses Fable to compile F# to JS. And I want to use Svelte with it, too. So far, I have compiled my F# file to a `.js` file. I've created a `.svelte` file with the following contents (named `App.svelte`)

```html
<script>
    import './App.fs.js'
</script>

<main>
    <p>{msg}</p>
</main>
<style></style>
```

My `index.html`:

```html
<body>
    <script src="main.mjs"></script>
</body>
```

And my `main.mjs`:

```js
import App from './App.svelte';

const app = new App({
    target: document.body,
    props: {
        name: 'world'
    }
});

export default app;
```

I run the program with `npm run build`. This compiles my F# files and they become ready.
I run `npm run tauri build -- --debug` to compile my whole Tauri app and open it.

I do this, and nothing shows on screen. But when I look at the console, it says `main.mjs`
cannot import.

Supposedly, I need to compile the Svelte files. But Svelte uses `rollup` and I think I need to use `webpack` to be compatible with Fable or Tauri.

All these files are in `project/src`.

**I need to compile and use a Svelte file in an `index.html`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give us a reproducible example to show us how you configured your project and what you've tried to get it working.

---

I give you here in this answer a working example to study, more than answering your question as it miss a lot of details about your setup.

Basically, to `npm run tauri build` your app, you will want to configure your project in order to build the **Fable** code, then **Svelte** code and then bundle everything with **Tauri**.

Also, you are not required to use webpack. Rollup is good.

*hint: if you really need webpack for some reason, just run it run it before rollup and you will find webpack svelte-loader on github*

I published a working template project to answer your question that you could use/study to check what you are missing. It was just created by following this flow:

- Project: https://github.com/flydev-fr/fable-svelte-tauri-app

1. create the Svelte app
   `yarn create svelte-app`
2. create the Tauri app
   `yarn create tauri-app`
3. create the Fable app

```
dotnet new --install Fable.Template
dotnet new fable
```

Then after that, it's just a mater of combining / merging everything, and adding Tauri to the Svelte app. **Please check the project to see how I configured it**

If you have more precise question, please make another question.